# Nested array object getting stripped after PUT request angular to express

Tags: angularjs, express

I am trying to send data to update my MongoDB database. Client side is Angular, which is correctly sending the data. I checked this by intercepting the data with Postman, so I know the PUT request has my data.

```
{val1: 'Some Val', val2:[{v21: 'test', v22: 'test', v23: true}]}
```

I'm not sending val3 in my request object. But on my server, covered by Express, my request object is :

```
{val1: 'Some Val', val2:[], val3:{v3:'test'}}
```

I have set:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
```

My controller code:

```
 var obj1 = new ObjService(vm.obj);
 obj1.$update(function (response) {
  //Returns nothing coz val2.length === 0
 }, function (errResponse) {
 });
```

My model

```
var ObjSchema = new Schema({
  val1:{
       type:String,
       default:''
  },
  val2:[{
    v21:{
     type: String
    },
    v22:{
     type: String
     },
    v23:{
     type: Boolean
    }
   }],
  val3:{
    v3:{
     type:String
     default: 'test'
    }
  } 
});
```

My express middleware

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
   console.log('Inside update');
   console.dir(req.obj); //Shows val2:[]
   var o = req.obj;
   if(o.val2.length >0){
      //Processing val2 - Never gets to this point
   }else{
     res.status(400).send({
        message: 'Val2 is empty'
     });
   }
 });
```

I'm not doing anything to the request object at all at this point. Update works absolutely fine for val1 and val3 also.

What could be causing this?

EDIT: Tried converting PUT request to POST and changed model to

```
var NestSchema = new Schema({
 v21:{
  type: String
 },
 v22:{
  type: String
  },
 v23:{
  type: Boolean
 }
});

var ObjSchema = new Schema({
 val1:{
     type:String,
     default:''
 },
 val2:[NestSchema],
 val3:{
  v3:{
   type:String
   default: 'test'
  }
 } 
});
```

POSTMAN still showing val2 object, but request object on server still shows empty array.

Comment: Please show us the express middleware where this is processed

Answer (score 0):

I feel foolish. I was accessing the wrong request object value. The req.obj value was the default object value being sent, whereas the edited value was within req.body.

So

```
 var o = req.body;  //instead of req.obj
```

Fixed it.